# Apple Macbook pro 2017 touchbar partially gone dark

Tags: macbook-pro

I realised that I am seeing my touch bar on MBP 2017 15" like this (Picture Bellow), and the button still works when I touch it, but I don't see it, its dark. Look at F12 key , after F11 key.

Could this be a cable issue ?, I reset NVRAM, SMC and tried safe boot too.

[image]

Comment: Related? [can Black strip on LCD screen of MBP 2017 be fixed with display cable replacement?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451767/can-black-strip-on-lcd-screen-of-mbp-2017-be-fixed-with-display-cable-replacemen)

Comment: This I realised months after the LCD issue, but that may be because when I saw issues with screen I add external display and kept using it with LCD closed. So I never saw this before.